# Нужна помощь совместить код вывода таксоомий для вордпрес?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код вывода картинок кастомных таксоомий:

```js
$args = array(
    'type' => 'lyric',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'item'
);
foreach ( get_categories( $args ) as $taxonomy_cat)
{
echo '<li>' . 
wp_get_attachment_image( $taxonomy_cat->term_image, 'thumbnail' ) .
$taxonomy_cat->name . 
'</a></li>';
}
```

И отдельный код, который выводит ссылки этих таксомий:

```js
<ul>
<?php $hiterms = get_terms("item", array("orderby" => "slug", "parent" => 0, "hide_empty" => 0)); ?>
<?php foreach($hiterms as $key => $hiterm) : ?>
<li>
<?php $term_link = get_term_link( $hiterm ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>">
<span><?php echo

 $hiterm->name; ?></span>

</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Нужно просто-напросто обернуть в сылку верхний код картинок. Не силен в php, прошу у знающих людей помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то:

```
<ul>
<?php $hiterms = get_terms("item", array("orderby" => "slug", "parent" => 0, "hide_empty" => 0)); ?>
<?php foreach($hiterms as $key => $hiterm) : ?>
<li>
<?php $term_link = get_term_link( $hiterm ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>">
<span><?php
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $hiterm->term_image, 'thumbnail' ); 
echo $hiterm->name; ?></span>

</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @евгенийрешетников если ответ помог - стоит отметить его решённым